# Combine UPDATE query into one single query for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have these queries, I would like to combine these queries into one without running this 2 times.
I tried combining this with the `OR` condition! Is this the best way to do this?

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `item` = 'abc' WHERE `name` = 'apple' OR `name` = 'orange';


UPDATE `table_name` SET `item` = 'abc' WHERE `name` = 'apple';

UPDATE `table_name` SET `item` = 'abc' WHERE `name` = 'orange';
```

Comment: You could also use case but it’s no better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
if you don't like OR operator you could try an IN clause

```
    UPDATE table_name 
    SET item = 'abc' 
    WHERE name IN ( 'apple' , 'orange');
```

pratically there are the same  ..

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know if there are any other ways too! :)